# Excel automatically performing 2 level sorting

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have a very simple list. Column A contains a list of movies and Column B contains their status, either "Watched" or "Not Watched". I want a list sorted alphabetically by movie name. When I click the **Sort A to Z** button(with active cell in column A), it gives me a alphabetical list of *Watched* movies first and then an alphabetical list of *Not Watched* movies. Exactly like if I did 2 level sorting, first by name and then status.
Why is this? How can I get a list sorted only by movie name regardless of if it's status?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue; it works like you want it for me. do you have any macros or other fancy stuff in your sheet? Can you post a screencopy?

Comment: If I create a small, mock list then that works exactly like how I want it to and how it should. This leads me to conclude that there must be something in the data that must be causing this instead of some global settings. I don't have any active macros, no fancy stuff, just a very simple list.
I doubt a screecopy will help so here's the link to the file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4uFbvcRQ3GYWGZtUE9tVnc2M3c

Comment: Yes, this file does the same thing for me. I tried all kinds of things, but cannot identify the issue. Maybe it is supposed to be a feature. You certainly got me flabbergasted, I would have bet my arm that it's something you do wrong, but no, it is _real_.

Comment: Thanks for dedicating some of your time to helping me out. I found the problem, I've posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Turns out that when I copied the data from Notepad, it somehow messed up the data but not visually. Whenever I tried to edit a cell, the text would behave very weirdly. This time, I didn't use the import wizard so it went fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify what you already found,
when I copied the first 14 rows of your spreadsheet
and pasted them into a text window (e.g., Notepad),
I got this:

```
Movie Name      Status
"                                       10 Cloverfield Lane"    Watched
12 Angry Men    Not Watched
"                                       12 Monkeys"     Watched
"                                       12 Years a Slave"       Watched
"                                       10,000 BC"      Watched
"                                       2 Fast 2 Furious"       Watched
"                                       21 Jump Street" Watched
"                                       22 Jump Street  "       Watched
"                                       28 Days Later           "       Watched
"                                       71      "       Watched
"                                       300     "       Watched
"                                       300: Rise of an Empire" Watched
5 Centimeters Per Second        Not Watched
```

Every movie that you had watched
had five Tab characters at the beginning of its name. 
Every movie that you had not watched was as it appeared. 
I got a hunch as to what was happening when I cleared Column `B`
and still got the same results from sorting Column `A`
— i.e., Excel wasn’t doing two-level sorting<sup>1</sup>;
it was getting those results just by sorting Column `A`. 
Then I entered `=CODE(A2)` into cell `C2` and dragged down. 
All the watched movies displayed 9 (the ASCII value of Tab);
the unwatched movies displayed the ASCII value
of the first character of their name
(i.e., numbers ranging between 49 for `1` to 90 for `Z`).

I don’t know why Excel didn’t make the Tabs easier to detect (i.e., visible).
______________
<sup>1</sup> By the way, you got it backwards in your question. 
The effect you were getting
was as if you were sorting first by status and then by name.

Comment: Yeah, I actually imported that list from notepad and thats how I kept it in notepad. Thanks for your help.